# merging two multisites

Tags: multisite, merging

I need to merge two existing multistes. Each has some 40 blogs, and the end result should be that all 80 blogs reside on one WP installation.

Any advice or experience on how to best apporach this task, other man doing it manually, by creating each new blog and user on the end server, and then use export/import for each individual new blog?

I'd like it to be an efficient method, that could also be applied on much larger multisites. Direct DB manipulation and Script automatization..

I'm interested in paying for assistance, if anyone has proven experience, or can suggest a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on the setup of the two current multisites:

- Do they share a common user base, if any?
- What kind of plugins are installed, if any?
- Likewise themes?
- Is it obvious which one is going to be imported in to the other?
- How many different authors are there? Things like author IDs will possibly have to be synchronised?
- What about user comments?

The reason for all these questions is that at the base of it, each site will have it's on wp_X tables. So merging the databases won't necessarily be so difficult, although obviously one set of database will need to be renamed. Then you'd need to update the wp_blogs table accordingly.

But once you start thinking about all the above questions it has the potential to get really messy and I am not sure if automating it is possible (or if worth the effort for 40 sites compared to doing it manually as you suggested).